# How to export a FusionChart to Image in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, export, fusioncharts, save-as

We are using the free version of fusion charts and want to know is there a way to export the generated chart to image without using any third party components. We are using the ASP.Net for generating the charts.

Comment: Do you want to generate a image, like a jpeg file?

Comment: Yes, I need the generate the fusion chart created in swf to image file in any of the format like png, JPEG etc programmatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After a research on this topic, I have found a useful solution for this.

For that we need to have a freeware from Bytecout to convert swf to image. This can be downloaded from this [link](http://bytescout.com/products/developer/swftoimagesdk/swftoimage.html).

Then we need to register the COM dlls and add the reference to our project. Refer to the below for further usage

```
Protected Sub btnSwf2ImgConverter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim swfobj As New SWFToImage.SWFToImageObject
    swfobj.InitLibrary("demo", "demo")
    swfobj.InputSWFFileName = Server.MapPath("dumps/swf/") & "FCF_MSColumn3D.swf"
    If ddlImageExtension.SelectedValue = "jpg" Then
        swfobj.ImageOutputType = TImageOutputType.iotJPG
        ext = ".jpg"
    Else
        If ddlImageExtension.SelectedValue = "gif" Then
            swfobj.ImageOutputType = TImageOutputType.iotGIF
            ext = ".gif"
        Else
            If ddlImageExtension.SelectedValue = "png" Then
                swfobj.ImageOutputType = TImageOutputType.iotPNG
                ext = ".png"
            Else
                If ddlImageExtension.SelectedValue = "bmp" Then
                    swfobj.ImageOutputType = TImageOutputType.iotBMP
                    ext = ".bmp"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    filenm = "FCF_Column3D" & ext
    swfobj.Execute_Begin()
    'swfobj.Execute()
    swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("dataXML", "<graph animation='0' formatNumber='1' divLineColor='ff5904' divLineAlpha='20' alternateHGridAlpha='5'  canvasBorderColor='666666'  baseFontColor='666666' showAlternateHGridColor='1' AlternateHGridColor='ff5904'  anchorSides='3' rotateNames='1' caption='Daily Reports' yAxisMinValue='0' yAxisMaxValue='1'  xAxisName='Day-Month-Year' yAxisName='Percentage' decimalPrecision='2'  numdivlines='8' numVdivlines='16' showhovercap='1'  formatNumberScale='0'> <categories> <category name='1-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='2-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='3-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='4-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='5-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='6-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='7-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='8-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='9-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='10-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='11-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='12-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='13-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='14-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='15-Jun-2010' showName='1' /> <category name='Aggregate' showName='1' /></categories><dataset  showValues='0' alpha='80' showAnchors='1' seriesname='Answered Percent' color='#f07979' lineThickness='2'><set name='Month' value='97.6'/><set name='Month' value='98.2'/><set name='Month' value='99.3'/><set name='Month' value='99.6'/><set name='Month' value='95.2'/><set name='Month' value='99.3'/><set name='Month' value='99.3'/><set name='Month' value='98.8'/><set name='Month' value='97.5'/><set name='Month' value='96.3'/><set name='Month' value='98.6'/><set name='Month' value='99.1'/><set name='Month' value='99.3'/><set name='Month' value='99.6'/><set name='Month' value='99.2'/><set name='Month' value='98.38'/></dataset></graph>")
    swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("chartWidth", "750")
    swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("chartHeight", "600")
    swfobj.ImageWidth = 600
    swfobj.ImageHeight = 500
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)

    swfobj.Execute_GetImage()
    swfobj.SaveToFile(Server.MapPath("dumps/images/" & filenm))
    swfobj.Execute_End()
    Call DownloadImage(filenm)
End Sub

Public Sub DownloadImage(ByVal fn As String)
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/dumps/images/" & fn
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(Server.MapPath("dumps/images/" & fn))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fn))
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    Response.WriteFile(fi.FullName)
    Response.Flush()
    fi.Delete()
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Here animation='0' plays a very important role, it specifies the fusion chart swf that, it must be loaded without animation. Also it is advisable if we sleep the code for 1 or 2 sec the swf would be loaded completely and image is converted to the selected format.

Hope this would be useful for someone like me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Screen capture.
2. License it.

Of course, there's also the free Asp.net charting controls ([here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)). [Here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/115/Microsoft-Chart-Controls-to-PDF-with-iTextSharp-and-ASP.NET-MVC)'s an example of how to export with those tools.

Comment: That great, but we are using the Fusion charts component; which generates the a swf file as chart. So please let me know how to export the chart as Image file.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for the links. These would be certainly useful for me in future.

Answer (score -1):

FusionCharts Team has developed a .NET assembly which will enable you to export chart at server without loading the chart in the browser.

You can have it by writing to FusionCharts Support at http://www.fusioncharts.com/contact/.

This only works for FusionCharts v3 charts.

Comment: OK, My Client don't want to pay for that. And I think FusionCharts v3 charts is a paid version.