# Blank image when Exporting fusionchart to image

Tags: c#, asp.net, fusioncharts

I'm trying to repeat an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003472/how-to-export-a-fusionchart-to-image-in-asp-net/8048274#8048274/) and rewrite the code on c#, but as a result I get a blank image. Where am I wrong?

```
        protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SWFToImage.ISWFToImageObject swfobj  = new SWFToImage.SWFToImageObject();
            swfobj.InitLibrary("demo", "demo");
            swfobj.InputSWFFileName = Server.MapPath("FusionCharts/") + "MSColumn2D.swf";
       swfobj.ImageOutputType = SWFToImage.TImageOutputType.iotJPG;
       string filenm = Server.MapPath("FusionCharts/" + "MSColumn2D.jpg"); 
swfobj.Execute_Begin();
swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("dataXML", "<chart yAxisName='Sales Figure' caption='Top 5 Sales Person' numberPrefix='$' useRoundEdges='1' bgColor='FFFFFF,FFFFFF' showBorder='0' ><set label='Alex' value='25000'  /><set label='Mark' value='35000' /> <set label='David' value='42300' /><set label='Graham' value='35300' /><set label='John' value='31300' /></chart>");
swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("chartWidth", "750");
swfobj.Execute_SetVariable("chartHeight", "600");
swfobj.ImageWidth = 600;
swfobj.ImageHeight = 500;      
swfobj.Execute_GetImage();
swfobj.SaveToFile(filenm);
swfobj.Execute_End();        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have missed out animation='0' in the dataXML, which I have mentioned in the post clearly. Also it is advisable to add

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

Before

```
swfobj.Execute_GetImage();
```

Thanks