# Need to convert multiple Fusion Chart to image from code behind

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

The problem is, I need to generate and send fusion graphs to a mail id on a scheduled basis. But as far as my R&D, fusion chart is having the functionality to export as image after rendering the graph in the page.
Another solution what i found in stackoverflow is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003472/how-to-export-a-fusionchart-to-image-in-asp-net). I.e with `SWFToImage` dll from bytescout. This dll does the job exactly what i wanted. but the problem is the dll is an activex library which is working only in 32 bit machine. So this dll is not working in our 64 bit server. Even bytescout dont have a solution for this.

Am plotting the fusion chart graphs like this,

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltlChart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

and am passing XML data source from code behind like this,

```
ltlChart.Text = FusionCharts.RenderChartHTML("../fusionCharts/MSLine.swf", "", xmlData, "ChartTitle", "100%", "250", false, true, true);
```

Please anyone help me to achieve my goal. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FusionCharts Labs has developed a .NET assembly allowing the exporting of Flash charts as images without rendering them in the browser, and now it has extended support for 64-bit applications.

Please note that you have to install 64-bit Flash Player.

For receiving the same, drop us a mail requesting for this assembly at support[@]fusioncharts.com.